# Android component to play video

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I have tried to play different formats and codecs in android (4.4) `webview` and `videoview` and found the following for API level 19:

1. `videoview` plays mp4 of some codecs, 3gp, flv but fails to play few mp4 codecs and mkv.
2. `webview` plays mp4 of all codecs, but fails to play video of any other format.

Vexed with the inconsistency in android components, what can be done to universally support all formats in any one or combination of components in android ?

Can I use external libraries to convert in runtime or abstract or bypass the complication of format/cedecs ?

P.S The question strictly pertains to API level 19, which is Android 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Youcan try library of video or audio player 
https://github.com/rtoshiro/FullscreenVideoView 
or 
https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/tree/master/vitamio